# How can I add a grey shaded web part

Tags: web-part, css

I have added a new community site, and I want to create a web part similar to the built-in “Community Tools” grey shaded area :-

[image: Screenshot]

I tried to add a content editor web part, but there is not an option to define the background color for this web part, can anyone advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Add your Content Editor WebPart
- Set Chrome to None
- Add HTML like this:

  ```
  <div class="ms-comm-adminLinks ms-core-defaultFont ms-noList"> 
    <div class="ms-webpart-titleText"> My Web Part </div> 
    <ul class="ms-comm-adminLinksList"> 
      <li class="ms-comm-adminLinksListItem"> 
         <a class="ms-link" href="/sites/C1/Lists/Community%20Discussion/Management.aspx">My Link</a>
      </li> 
    </ul> 
  </div>
  ```